# Изменить белый цвет фона изображения

Tags: php

Как заменить фон белого цвета картинки средствами php?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы уверены, что вам именно php для этого нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен GD или Imagic.

GD пример:
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php

```
$im = imagecreatefromgif("test.gif"); 
// Так же есть функции для чтения других форматов

$index = imagecolorclosest($im, 255, 255, 255); // Получить всё что белое
imagecolorset($im, $index, 92, 92, 92); // Меняем белое на серое.

imagegif($im, "result.gif"); // Сохраняем картинку
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Кто-то поставил минус - не хочет объяснить, что не так? Ответ правильный. Добавил плюс от себя.